# How to automatic load .feature files

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, cucumber, cucumberjs

Here is an example of the (react) architecture.

```
src/
 components/
  Input/
   Tests/
    Input.feature
    Input.test.js
```

We test with react testing library and cucumber for scenarios. But in each feature file we need to do

```
import { defineFeature, loadFeature } from 'jest-cucumber';

const feature = loadFeature('src/components/Input/Tests/Input.feature')

defineFeature(feature, test => {})
```

How to avoid systematically having to add the feature file in our tests. Is there a way to automate this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Create a file saying cucumber.js in your project root directory and add this code into it

```
   let common = [
  '--require ./support/', // Load hooks
  './**/tests/features/', // Specify our feature files
  '--require ./**/tests/steps/**/', // Load step definitions
].join(' ');

module.exports = {
  default: common
};
```

This will load your feature , spec and any support files at the time of cucumber execution initialization